# Makefile, "nothing to be done for all" error

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, makefile

So I have a make file, stored in a directory called "temp" the following directory has a src folder, with 2 .c files "file1.c" and "file2.c". The temp directory also holds a include folder (which is empty), and a bin folder (which is empty until the make command is so posed to be run). I'm currently to trying get a single .c file to compile (get it working),but a single file doesn't even seem to work here.

This is how the directories look:

```
temp
```

cd into temp..

```
bin include Makefile src
```

Here is my makefile:

```
all:
    gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 src/file1.c -Iinclude -o bin/runMe -lncurses
```

And yes, there is a tab before the gcc. Any help on this frustrating issue, would be much appreciated. Also, if possible any input on compiling the second .c file, would also be very helpful!

Comment: Nothing to be done for all isn't an error - it means there isn't anything new to compile since the last compilation.

Comment: I've edited the file, saved it, tried to recompile using make, and I get the same result.

Comment: please check again this "tab" before gcc (use editor which show whitespaces for it)

Comment: Cyclone, I tried that to no avail. And Marcin, I'm using nano as the editor, I don't have much other options on the raspberry pi I'm using.

Comment: Are you sure your editor doesn't convert tabs to spaces?

Comment: So just remove everything before gcc, and then press "TAB"  - to be sure.

Comment: I'm sshing onto the pi via a windows machine, but I'm still using Nano in the process (from my pi).

Comment: Check so you don't have the following set in your `~/.nanorc` file: `set tabstospaces`

Comment: @user20842454566 - You can also try to unexpand any spaces converting them to tabs like this: `unexpand makefile > makefile2` and then testing it using `make -f makefile2`

Comment: DrC: undelete your answer.  It is correct.

Comment: @user20842454566 - How did you solve the problem? Whas the reason whitespaces or something else?

Comment: This cannot be a TAB vs. spaces problem.  If it were then make would give the error: _missing separator_ as the makefile is parsed.  The fact that it starts to run the makefile means, clearly, there is no TAB vs. spaces problem.  The only way you'd get that message that I can see is if there were a file or directory named "all", but according to the post there isn't.  This is a mystery.  You could run `make -d` to find out what's going on.  Of course Etan and DrC have told you how to write the makefile correctly, but that doesn't explain the behavior you were seeing before.

Comment: I couldn't get my own makefile to work, so I used a template one that my school provided, which in turn worked. I believe the issue is with the tab not being recognized on my own raspberry pi, as I've tested this issue on a friends pi, and he does not appear to have this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Nothing to be done for TARGET` means that a target has no commands which, in this case, almost certainly means that you do not have a tab on that `gcc` line.

That being said that's only the immediate problem. This makefile is also not following good practices and will unnecessarily recompile your program (as well as ceasing to work entirely should an `all` file be created).

DrC had, in a currently deleted answer, very good suggestions for how to improve your makefile to avoid both of those latter issues.

Specically, your makefile should look more like this:

```
.PHONY: all
all: bin/runMe

bin/runMe: src/file1.c
     gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 $^ -Iinclude -o $@ -lncurses
```

Which marks the `all` target as a [`.PHONY`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) so that an `all` file or directory getting created won't confuse make as well as setting up a prerequisite on the source file for your built binary so that make can tell when it does (and doesn't) need to rebuild the binary.

Comment: Etan: if there were no TAB, you'd get _missing separator_ during parsing.  This makefile is syntactically legal, which means there absolutely IS a TAB before the `gcc`.

Comment: @MadScientist You are absolutely correct. Which leaves me unable to explain the initial output (unless it wasn't GNU Make I suppose).